# How can I calculate the monthly average of a column in a CSV, given that the CSV file has a column for dates as well

Tags: python, csv

This is what the CSV/Excel file looks like:

```
`2008-09-19 461 462.07  443.28  449.15  10006000    449.15
2008-09-18  422.64  439.18  410.5   439.08  8589400 439.08
2008-09-17  438.48  439.14  413.44  414.49  9126900 414.49
2008-09-16  425.96  449.28  425.49  442.93  6990700 442.93
2008-09-15  424 441.97  423.71  433.86  6567400 433.86
2008-09-12  430.21  441.99  429 437.66  6028000 437.66
2008-09-11  408.35  435.09  406.38  433.75  6471400 433.75
2008-09-10  424.47  424.48  409.68  414.16  6226800 414.16
2008-09-09  423.17  432.38  415 418.66  7229600 418.66
2008-09-08  452.02  452.94  417.55  419.95  9017900 419.95
2008-09-05  445.49  452.46  440.08  444.25  4534300 444.25
2008-09-04  460 463.24  449.4   450.26  4848500 450.26
2008-09-03  468.73  474.29  459.58  464.41  4314600 464.41
2008-09-02  476.77  482.18  461.42  465.25  6111500 465.25
2008-08-29  469.75  471.01  462.33  463.29  3848200 463.29
2008-08-28  472.49  476.45  470.33  473.78  3029700 473.78
`
```

I need to calculate the monthly average of the final column and store it in a list.

What I have so far is truly awful as I've been scrabbling crap-code together for a few days now struggling to get it right and I know for a fact there are far more efficient (and functional) ways to do it. For anyone who's interested, here's my current dysfunctional code:

```
def get_monthly_averages (data_list):
    date_list = []
    monthly_average_list = []
    current_date = ''
    nums = []
    count = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0
    for index, row in enumerate(data_list):
        data_list[index] = row.split(",")
    for index, row in enumerate(data_list):
        if index > 0:
            date_list.append(row[0])
            data_list[index] = [float(i) for i in row if row.index(i) > 0]
    for index, row in enumerate(data_list):
        if index == 1:
            current_date = str(date_list[index-1])
            current_date = current_date[:-3]
            count += 1
            nums = row[5:6]

        elif index > 1 and current_date in date_list[index - 1]:
            nums = row[5:6]




            monthly_average_list.append(average)

        elif index > 1 and current_date not in date_list[index - 1]:
            current_date = str(date_list[index-1])
            current_date = current_date[:-3]
            nums = row[5:6]
            total = 0




    print(monthly_average_list[0])
    print(current_date)
    print(date_list[0])
    print(data_list[1])    

    return monthly_average_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand the result you're going for, yes, I think you've overthought the solution. If you want the month-wise average of a column, all you need to do is find all the cells in that column, group them up by month, and average them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_col_avg_by_month(data, colnumber):
    result = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for row in (row.split() for row in data):
        date = year, month = row[0].split('-')[:2]
        result[tuple(date)].append(float(row[colnumber]))
    return {date: avg(data) for date, data in result.items()}
```

Here, for each row we grab the month (which we pair with the year to differentiate between September of 2017 and September of 2016) and append the cell of the target column to that month's result list (we use a `defaultdict` so that the first time we put in a new month, we start with an empty list). Finally, right before we return, we recompute the result dict to hold the average of the data set, rather than the data set itself (`avg = lambda lst: sum(lst) / len(lst)`).

[demo](https://repl.it/Jn7y)